# How does Amazon's Elastic IP work? What would I have to do if I wanted to create a similar system myself?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, networking

I can't seem to find the right combination of search terms to google for this answer, but what would I have to do if I wanted to create my own elastic ip that I could point to any other up address using my own private hosting? What would some of the bottlenecks be?

To add more detail: Amazon's Elastic is not simply a server that you pass requests too and it then makes the requests for you and passes back the data that's returned like some sort of VPN. Their service allows you to make a request to one IP address and have it be as if you made that request to another IP address entirely. How do they do this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tI believe this can be done via simple [`iptables`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables) rules and [Network Address Translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) (NAT), I am unsure how AWS does it on their backend.

A simple rule

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 99.99.99.99 -j DNAT --to-destination 12.34.56.78
```

In this rule, we will be adding a rule to the top of the `NAT Prerouting` table, this will be the first rule evaluate by every packet - be weary, many rules will slow down your packet flow - you should study up on iptables if you go down this route.

Here, we will be taking a packet destined to `99.99.99.99` - and the `DNAT` rule will simply rewrite the destination IP of the packet, and send it on its way.

To delete the rule, simply change the `-I` to `-D`.

A basic failover of the above rule to a new server

```
iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -d 99.99.99.99 -j DNAT --to-destination 12.34.56.78 # Delete existing forward
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 99.99.99.99 -j DNAT --to-destination 87.65.43.21 # Add new forward
```

Note that you will also need to have rules in the `Filter Forward` table as well for each destination you plan to send packets to.

```
iptables -t filter -I FORWARD -d 12.34.56.78 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -I FORWARD -d 87.65.43.21 -j ACCEPT
```

*edit*

You have asked about load balancing, so here is this as well, load balancing connections between 3 hosts.

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 99.99.99.99 --mode nth --every 1 --packet 0 -j DNAT --to-destination x.y.z.1
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 99.99.99.99 --mode nth --every 2 --packet 0 -j DNAT --to-destination x.y.z.2
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 99.99.99.99 --mode nth --every 3 --packet 0 -j DNAT --to-destination x.y.z.3
```

If you wanted to restrict this to either HTTP / HTTPS, you would filter those ports accordingly:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 99.99.99.99 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 12.34.56.78:80
```

It may help, it may just be even more confusing, but [here is a page with some useful rules](https://crm.vpscheap.net/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=29).

Comment: Can the downvoter explain? This will do exactly as asked.

Comment: Someone downvoted you. Can whoever did it please tell us why he is wrong?

Comment: Also @Matt what if I wanted to do this in real-time using something like python to decide where to reroute the packet?

Comment: Hi @RyanWeinstein, I have added a few more details to my answer. Deciding _where_ to route the packet is going to be up to your own logic, I have added example for a basic failover here too.

Comment: This seems to be the way to do it if I just wanted to redirect all packets from a source to destination, but how would I do things like redirect per 'http request' rather than per packet? Or if two packets came at once but I wanted to redirect one to one destination and the other to another destination?

Comment: Even more added for ya.

Comment: Great! I've used iptables before to do simple firewalling and ddos protection but I never knew it had so many features. Thanks Matt!

Comment: I just added in a link to a page I use often as well, outlining a lot more.